# Doubt and contradiction on Electromagnetism and about combination of Relativity and Quantum Mechanics, according to Feynman Lectures on Physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity

In Feynman's famous Physics book, "The Feynman Lectures on Physics", in a discussion of the generality of Maxwell's equations in the static case, in which he addresses the problem of whether they are an approximation of a deeper mechanism that follows other equations or not, he says [Vol. II, Sec. 12-7 (The “underlying unity” of nature), Par. 7]:

> Strangely enough, it turns out (for reasons that we do not at all
> understand) that the combination of relativity and quantum mechanics
> as we know them seems to *forbid* the invention of an equation that is
> fundamentally different from $\begin{align}
> \nabla \cdot{(\kappa \nabla{\phi})}&=-\frac{\rho_{\text{free}}}{\epsilon_0}.
> \end{align}$, and which does not at the
> same time lead to some kind of contradiction. Not simply a
> disagreement with experiment, but an *internal contradiction*.

I was wondering first of all if this was a personal observation of Feynman's, or if it was a known thing that I will find in the future while studying and will somehow be pointed out to me in some Physics course. Then I was wondering: could we understand qualitatively what are we talking about? I.e.: how does one theory ensure that there cannot be another different and more precise theory for the phenomena it describes?

Combining Quantum Mechanics and Relativity (especially General Relativity) I think we get to very, very, very complicated things. At this point, could Feynman's point be understood like this: "people have tried for a long time to build theories that combine them and in all cases Poisson-style equations popped up somewhere, so there's no theory on the horizon that seems to work but doesn't have that kind of structure"?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you include exactly what eq.(12.4) that Feynman refers to is? It would make this question essentially self contained whilst without it I have to dig out a copy of Feynman and find the equation he is talking about

Comment: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_12.html#Ch12-S7

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't thought about what you pointed out, you are absolutely right. I edited the OP, replacing the mark "Eq. (12.4)" with the equation to which it referred.

Comment: It is worth quoting the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: As, for example, the prediction that the sum of the probabilities of all possible occurrences is not equal to unity, or that energies may sometimes come out as complex numbers, or some other such idiocy. No one has yet made up a theory of electricity for which $∇^2ϕ=−ρ/ϵ_0$ is understood as a smoothed-out approximation to a mechanism underneath, and which does not lead ultimately to some kind of an absurdity.

Comment: But, it must be added, it is also true that the assumption that $∇^2ϕ=−ρ/ϵ_0$ is valid for all distances, no matter how small, leads to absurdities of its own (the electrical energy of an electron is infinite)—absurdities from which no one yet knows an escape.

Comment: While progress has been made, it is still true today that nobody has come up with a theory that resolves these absurdities.

Comment: No, you are misreading Feynman. He is not saying that we are studying what equations are possible and realising that different equations would fail (even though we actually did do a bit of that). He is saying that people have been trying many alternatives and those have all failed. It does not forbid us from trying ever more elaborate schemes, but that the simple schemes have all failed. It is, of course, however still interesting that we can restrict our attention to a much stringent class of equations at all.

Comment: @mmesser314 If someone had a model in which the electric field is quantised and represented by newly introduced elementary particles, then it would follow that both the electric and the magnetic field of an electron are finite.